# Unexpected Behavior of <div> with child <a> (anchor tag)

Tags: html, css

A Page has 3 div

```css
    div
    {
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 10px;
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     background-color: #333;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <div></div> <!--Div 1-->
    <div></div> <!--Div 2-->
    <div></div> <!--Div 3-->
```

which produce folowing result.[image]

But when I nest an anchor tag in any of the div.

```
<div></div> <!--Div 1-->
<div></div> <!--Div 2-->
<div>       <!--Div 3 with anchor tag-->
    <a href="#">Anchor Tag</a>
</div>
```

That div is pushed down but why.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use vertical-align:___; When you use display:inline-block;.It is associate property of inline-block;Bu default it is aligned to bottom of neibour .

```
div
{
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 10px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #333;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: but other two are also inline-block and they are not aligned to the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

Use **vertical-align: top;**. It will help you. [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/priyasingh/saate5zx/)

```
div {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 10px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #333;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **float:left;**

```css
div
{
 margin: 10px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #333;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 float:left;
}
```

```html
<div></div> <!--Div 1-->
<div></div> <!--Div 2-->
<div>       <!--Div 3 with anchor tag-->
    <a href="#">Anchor Tag</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a parent div and assigned it parent class. The three divs have child class. I made parent inline-flex and child inline-block.

```css
 .child
     {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 10px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: #333;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      }

     .parent{
      display:inline-flex;
      }
```

```html
     <div class="parent">

     <div class="child"></div> <!--Div 1-->
     <div class="child"></div> <!--Div 2-->
     <div class= "child">

     text new

     </div>
     </div>
```